# What could restrict dataflow pipeline to only using a single worker?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've been trying to debug a pipeline which takes a input parameter that drives subsequent ParDo operations. For reasons that I cannot fathom, the pipeline will not scale beyond a single worker even though I've disabled autoscaling and set the number of workers. Sadly the abysmal dataflow interface on GCP does little to illuminate the inability to scale. Can anyone advise as to what might be the issue or how to debug effectively?

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=opts) as p:
  result = (
      p | "Initialize Pipeline" >> beam.Create(
          [(f'gs://data/']) |
      "Scan for extraction tasks" >> beam.ParDo(scanner.ScanForTasks()) |
      "Extract data" >> beam.ParDo(worker.TaskToData()))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to be related to an optimization in dataflow called '[fusion](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#fusion-optimization)' in which adjacent operations are fused together, presumably so that they can run seamlessly on the same worker. The problem is that if a pipeline is seeded by a single item which generates a large number of downstream tasks, all these tasks will then be processed on the same worker that handled the initial seeding task.

The solution is to seed the pipeline directly with the tasks to prevent this 'optimization' from killing performance

```
def scan_for_tasks():
  tasks = []
  # Build your task list here
  return tasks

with beam.Pipeline(options=opts) as p:
  result = (
    p | "Initialize Pipeline" >> beam.Create(scan_for_tasks()) |
    "Extract data" >> beam.ParDo(worker.TaskToData()))
```

Comment: thanks for sharing! You can also add a `beam.Reshuffle()` transform that should allow you to shuffle tasks between workers if necessary.

Comment: Hi Pablo. It would be really helpful if the dataflow UI could visually convey to the user which steps have been fused and that the branching ratio for each step is. This would allow users to easily see when something like this occurs. I really struggled to determine what was happening with the current UI...

Comment: thanks. That's reasonable feedback. Some steps are marked with "stages", which are the fused units of execution, but I agree that it's not explicit enough